# List without negative indexing

Tags: python, list

I am coding a simply discrete system in Python which is presented below:

```
class System:
  def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.y = []


  def dynamics(self, signal):
    for i in range(len(signal)):
      try:
         self.y.append(signal[i] - self.a*self.y[i-1] - self.b*self.y[i-2])
      except:
        try:
           self.y.append(signal[i] - self.a*self.y[i-1] - self.b*0)
        except:
           self.y.append(signal[i] - self.a*0 - self.b*0)
```

The class System aims to model the system and the method dynamics to compute the dynamic system evolution through discrete time. I thought that would be a good idea to use the try/except structure to deal with the first steps of the system - in our case the first two steps - in each some previous values of y would be not available. Well, this approach would work, if the list object does not accepted negative index, which is not the case.

I know that I could solve this problem with other implementation approaches but, I would like to keep with this one. So, this is my question, how could I create a list object and disable negative indexing. I would appreciate some chunks of code.

Comment: Why fight the language? Better to write code that fits the language than to twist the language to fit your code.

Comment: Creating something just to make it work in a `try except` block is not a good idea. Imagine you are Guido, you are designing a syntax for users to easily handle errors in their code, and people start creating `type`'s to work with that syntax. How would you feel ?

Comment: @Rockybilly he might be pleased that meta-programming made his tool more useful. See for instance django.

Comment: You could create your own list-like object as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839305/can-you-easily-create-a-list-like-object-in-python-that-uses-something-like-a-de and add that constraint.

Comment: @tdelaney Such as in my answer.

Comment: Don't use a bare `except`; be explicit and catch the error that your code actually handles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I pointed out my reluctance in the comments, I'll play your game.

```
class PositiveList(list):

    def __getitem__(self, ind):
        if ind < 0:
            raise IndexError("Expected a positive index, instead got {}.".format(ind))
        return super(PositiveList, self).__getitem__(ind)

x = PositiveList([1, 2, 3])
print x[-1]
#IndexError: Expected a positive index, instead got -1.
```

Comment: You also need to typecheck the index, since slicing also uses `__getitem__` (with a `slice` object as the index).

Comment: @Blckknght You are right, however, OP doesn't seem to need it in that particular part of the code.

Comment: Oh, I guess slicing actually works by coincidence in Python 2, where slices compare as greater than integers. In Python 3 comparing them is an error.

Comment: @Blckknght It works, but it does not raise an error with negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you actually want and is much cleaner. Just keep the latest two y-values in extra variables.

```
def dynamics(self, signal):
    y1 = y2 = 0
    for sig in signal:
        y1, y2 = sig - self.a * y1 - self.b * y2, y1
        self.y.append(y1)
```